# How to write IF loops in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that is:

```
   Gender               bravo            charlie
1      M    1.45811622227195 -0.647499970684844
2      F  -0.254538222090381 -0.239702952615991
3      M   0.754671518799496  0.636660794586513
4      M   0.867227804662325 -0.107523939903046
5      F   0.726354342589917  0.398665397744101
6      M    -1.2904135038184  0.483559717259751
7      F -0.0982799006827993 -0.900361808856964
8      M   -1.36889826752091  -1.31789772901583
9      M  -0.941069689516976 -0.119062225146744
10     F  -0.224327632607696   -1.3353714767836
```

(1) Want to write a function that differentiates M from F. Like after I run it, I only get

```
   Gender               bravo            charlie
1      M    1.45811622227195 -0.647499970684844
2      M   0.754671518799496  0.636660794586513
3      M   0.867227804662325 -0.107523939903046
...
```

(2) Want to write a similar function but this time I want only rows that contain `charlie >= 0`.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post any code that you may have attempted? What specifically are you having problems with? The SO community will help you to debig problems, we will not write your code for you.

Comment: Maybe something like: df.1[df.1$Gender == 'M',] or df.1[df.1$Gender == 'M' & df.1$charlie >= 0,]

Comment: I am learning this language and made this random vector. Anyways, I called that vector 'c'. What I tried so far is:

function()
{
if c$Gender == "M"

And it gives me error here.

Comment: I see 2 votes to close.  I understand the downvotes but the votes to close as `it is too difficult to understand what is being asked here` doesn't make sense.  It's very straight forward what is being asked here.  For a first time poster that gives us a data set and expected outcome I'd say this is a bit harsh and a bit more redirection and teaching is in order instead.

Comment: @Tyler: agree on this; closing may discourage newbie from learning R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume this is your first day/time using R.  The solution you're looking for is a vectorized approach that uses **indexing**.  First let me introduce you to the [R introduction manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf).  Well worth the time reading it as the question you ask is pretty straight forward.  This first answer is a freebie in that I'm giving the benefit of the doubt that you don't even know where to search but the introductory manual will get you moving in the right direction (I started there myself at some point).  Page 10 would be a good place to start for this question.  R has a number of great resources and manuals that are easily googled.

Ok...

1) If your data frame is named dat:

```
dat[dat$Gender == "M", ]
```

2) ...

```
dat[dat$charlie >= 0, ]
```

Comment: or, assuming the data frame is dat, use `subset`: 1) `subset(dat, Gender=="M")` 2) `subset(dat, charlie>=0)` or if you want male and positive charlie then, `subset(data, Gender=="M" & charlie>==0)`